# Slick 3 multiple dependant inserts causes deadlock

Tags: scala, slick, akka-stream

I'm trying to insert a series of records into two tables, where the second tables' primary key is also a foreign key to the first tables' id. The second table also has a unique constraint on another column. I need to insert to the first, get its id (AutoInc) and then insert into the second. Inserting new records works fine, but if I try to insert an existing record the entire system appears to stop working. I am using akka stream to stream records from a (rather large) file and call the insert method record by record. After a failure i don't understand why the entire stream stops. It's like the future never completes, even though the error is printed.

The code:

```
def actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("loader")
  def materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()(actorSystem)
  def ex: ExecutionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher
  import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource

  val database = {
    val ds = new ComboPooledDataSource
    ds.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver")
    ds.setJdbcUrl("...")
    ds.setUser("...")
    ds.setPassword("...")
    Database.forDataSource(ds)
  }

  val db = database
  val reader = CSVReader.open(args(0))
  val kind = "postcode"

  Source.fromIterator(() => reader.iteratorWithHeaders)
    .map(l =>
      ((l.get("pcd").get, l.get("pcd").get, kind),(l.get("pcd").get.toLowerCase.replaceAll("\\s",""), l.get("osward").get.toLowerCase.replaceAll("\\s","")))
    )
    .map({i => println(i); i})
    .runWith(Sink.foreach({i => insert(i._1, i._2)}))(materializer)


  def insert(location: (String, String, String), pc: (String, String)): Unit = {
    println("begin")
    val locationInsert = LocationTable.rows.map(l => (l.name, l.description, l.kind)) returning LocationTable.rows.map(_.id)
    val pcInsert = PostcodeLocationTable.rows.map(r => (r.id, r.postcode, r.osward))
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    val fullInsert = for {
      l <- locationInsert += location
      _ <- pcInsert += (l, pc._1, pc._2)
    } yield ()
    val f = db.run(fullInsert.transactionally)

    f.onComplete{
      case Success(i) => println(s"inserted $i rows")
      case Failure(ex) => println(s"errorrrr ${ex.getMessage}")
    }

    Await.result(f, Duration(1, SECONDS))
    println("end")
  }
```

The output:

```
((AB1 0AA,AB1 0AA,postcode),(ab10aa,s13002484))
begin
errorrrr ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PostcodeLocation_postcode_79955aee_uniq"
  Detail: Key (postcode)=(ab10aa) already exists.
```

The Await call never progresses even though the duration is set to 1 second. It's like the error causes everything to deadlock. Same result if I remove transactionally.